# How to prepare sql statements and bind parameters?

Tags: c++, sqlite, prepared-statement

Unfortunatelly, the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org) completely lacks examples (what is really strange), as if it assumes all its readers to be good programmers. Whereas, I'm quite new to `C++` and can not really figure out from the documentation how to really prepare and execute statements. I love the way how it is implemented in `PDO` for `PHP`. Normally, I just do it like this:

```
$s = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id = :id");
$s->bindParam(':id', $id);
$s->execute();
```

or do it using `?` tokens:

```
 $data = array();
 $data[] = 1;
 $data[] = 2;
 $s = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE id = ? or id = ?");
 $s->execute($data);
```

Now, I have `C++` and `sqlite3.h` in my hands. At this moment, I know just how to connect to database - I do it and get no errors:

```
sqlite3 * conn;
int rc = sqlite3_open(db_name, &conn);
```

Please, give some instructions (with clear tiny examples) about how to implement similar things that `PDO` does in `PHP` - prepare a statement using named arguments and using `?` tokens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find a decent amount of documentation here: [sqlite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/)
This example does not explain the `sqlite3` function calls and parameters in detail, as that is quite a lot of information to cover - instead refer to the given link for more in-depth detail.

This example binds values to the statement in your question multiple times, and reads all query results after each bind:

```
sqlite3* conn;
sqlite3_stmt* stmt = 0;

int rc = sqlite3_open(db_name, &conn);
//  Good idea to always check the return value of sqlite3 function calls. 
//  Only done once in this example:
if ( rc != SQLITE_OK ) { // Do something }

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2( conn, "SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE id = ? or id = ?", -1, &stmt, 0 );

//  Optional, but will most likely increase performance.
rc = sqlite3_exec( conn, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0 );    

for ( int bindIndex = 0; bindIndex < number_of_times_you_wish_to_bind; bindIndex++ ) {
    //  Binding integer values in this example.
    //  Bind functions for other data-types are available - see end of post.

    //  Bind-parameter indexing is 1-based.
    rc = sqlite3_bind_int( stmt, 1, int_you_wish_to_bind ); // Bind first parameter.
    rc = sqlite3_bind_int( stmt, 2, int_you_wish_to_bind ); // Bind second parameter.

    //  Reading interger results in this example.
    //  Read functions for other data-types are available - see end of post.
    while ( sqlite3_step( stmt ) == SQLITE_ROW ) { // While query has result-rows.
        //  In your example the column count will be 1.
        for ( int colIndex = 0; colIndex < sqlite3_column_count( stmt ); colIndex++ ) { 
            int result = sqlite3_column_int( stmt, colIndex );
            //  Do something with the result.
        }
    }
    //  Step, Clear and Reset the statement after each bind.
    rc = sqlite3_step( stmt );
    rc = sqlite3_clear_bindings( stmt );
    rc = sqlite3_reset( stmt );
}
char *zErrMsg = 0;  //  Can perhaps display the error message if rc != SQLITE_OK.
rc = sqlite3_exec( conn, "END TRANSACTION", 0, 0, &zErrMsg );   //  End the transaction.

rc = sqlite3_finalize( stmt );  //  Finalize the prepared statement.
```

[More Bind Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)

[More Read Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)

Comment: Thanks! I find your answer very useful.

Comment: What is `UTF8String`? I found a reference to it in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccertenroll/about-utf8string) stating it is used for ASN.1, but I don't see anything indicating this is Windows or ITU related.

Comment: @jww [UTF8String](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.UTF8String) is a compiler-specific string-type. It is redundant code, I will update the answers. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I just came here to see the `#include`s, but that was left out xD. For the next guy, you can find them using `pacman -Ql sqlite;`. It shows `/usr/include/sqlite3.h`. There's also `/usr/include/sqlite3ext.h` which I'm sure has all kinds of crazy cool features \o/!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from http://hoogli.com/items/Avoid_sqlite3_clear_bindings().html, the step `rc = sqlite3_clear_bindings( stmt );` is not necessary in this case.
Unfortunately, I am not yet allowed to post this as a comment to the very good previous answer.