# How to pass Sqlite query values as variables?

Tags: c, sqlite

My code is like this...

```
        char dis[20];
        int tc,tac,trc;
        puts("Enter the data:\n");
        puts("District : ");
        while((getchar())!='\n');
        fgets(dis,20,stdin);
        puts("Total Cases : ");
        scanf("%d",&tc);
        puts("Total Active Cases : ");
        scanf("%d",&tac);
        puts("Total Recovered Cases : ");
        scanf("%d",&trc);
        sql = "INSERT INTO COV VALUES (dis,tc,tac,trc);";   //won't work
        sql = "INSERT INTO COV VALUES ('abc',1,1,0);";      //works
        database = sqlite3_exec(db, sql,0,0,0);
```

I want to save the values obtained from user in sqlite database but I can't do it as shown below.

It works if I just pass the exact value (i.e. during compile time).
How can I send values computed during runtime execution to sqlite database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prepare sql statements and bind parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745465/how-to-prepare-sql-statements-and-bind-parameters)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to put the actual values in using sprintf

```
char sqlscript[128];
```

Then, since you are using sql to send to the DB, assign sqlscript to sql first

```
sql = sqlscript;
sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO COV VALUES('%s', %d, %d, %d);", dis, tc, tac, trc);
```

Comment: And then `dis` is something like `'); drop table cov; --`

Comment: This is for a very simple case where you assume that there is no sql injection.  Typically an internal application for generating reports.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the Sqlite [C interface](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) documentation.

Assuming you have a table defined like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE COV (id PRIMARY KEY, dis VARCHAR, tc INTEGER, tac INTEGER, trc INTEGER);
```

You need to bind your parameters with specific `bind` API to prevent SQL injection.

Prepare your `INSERT` string using `?N` template:

```
char sql[512];
snprintf(sql, sizeof(sql), "INSERT INTO COV(dis, tc, tac, trc) VALUES (?1,?2,?3,?4);");
```

Then bind your program variables with the corresponding parameter:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, sizeof(sql), &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, dis, 20, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, tc);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 3, tac);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, trc);

ret = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if (ret == SQLITE_DONE)
    printf("record inserted!\n");
else
    printf("Error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```